# how to disable some column using insert trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table with 5 columns:

- `username` (`varchar`)
- `password` (`int`)
- `access` (`bit`)
- `information` (`varchar`)
- `image` (`varchar`)

I want to prevent user from inserting to 2 columns `information` and `image` if `access = true`.

Is there anyway to do this using insert trigger ? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an [`INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), you could easily "filter out" unwanted information, e.g. you could insert an empty string (or something else) in case that `access` is set to `1`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsteadTrigger on dbo.YourTableNameHere
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbo.YourTableNameHere(username, password, access, information, image)
       SELECT 
           username, password, access,
           CASE access  
              WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE i.information END,
           CASE access 
              WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE i.image END
       FROM INSERTED i
END;
```

So if you insert a row with `access = 0` - all the columns get stored as presented.

So if you try to insert a row with `access = 1` - the columns `information` and `image` are being "cleared out" and an empty string is stored instead.

On SQL Server **2008** and newer, this insert here:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTableNameHere(username, password,access,information, image)
VALUES  ('test 1', 42, 0, 'testinfo 1', 'testimg 1'),
        ('test 2', 4711, 1, 'testinfo 2', 'testimg2')

SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTableNameHere
```

would result in two rows being saved to your database table, but the second row inserted will have empty `information` and `image` columns...

Answer (score 0):

A simple CHECK constraint could be enough if you need this behavior at **insert or update**:

```
ALTER TABLE MySchema.MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MyTable_BlockInformationImageWhenAccessIsTrue
CHECK( access = 1 AND information IS NULL AND image IS NULL OR access = 0 );
```

If you need this behavior only at insert moment then you could use this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgI_MyTable_BlockInformationImageWhenAccessIsTrue
ON MySchema.MyTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM inserted i 
        WHERE i.access = 1 
        AND (information IS NOT NULL OR image IS NOT NULL)
    )
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    RAISERROR('Access denied', 16, 1);
    END
END;
GO
```